# In R: tab_model (hide polynomials)

Tags: r, model, regression, lme4, sjplot

is there any way to hide the quadratic/polynomial terms in the regression output?
It seems to show them by default which adds tons of rows, obviously.
Thanks so much!
Best
Clemens

Comment: It's not clear how you expect us to answer this question. Need many more details.

Comment: please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The developer answered this elsewhere:

https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/776#issuecomment-944883019

> The next update will include keep and drop arguments, that are a bit
> more flexible and allow you to define regular expression patterns like
> this:
>
> ```
> library(sjPlot)
>
> # load mtcars data
> data(mtcars)
>
> # factorize cyl variable
> mtcars$cyl.f <- factor(mtcars$cyl, ordered=TRUE)
>
> # set polynomial contrast for factorized cyl
> contrasts(mtcars$cyl.f) = contr.poly(3)
>
> # run linear regression model
> m <- lm(mpg ~ cyl.f, data=mtcars)
>
> # include all polynomials
> tab_model(m, keep ="\\.f")
>
> # remove all polynomials
> tab_model(m, drop ="\\.f")
> ```